# Eloquent query to LIKE query

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

:) In my 40-lines query (Eloquent, Laravel), I have this part:

```
->orWhere(function ($query) {
    $query
        ->where('questions.category', '=', Auth::user()->category);
})
```

This works OK, but I want to make it like: `'%questions.category%' LIKE Auth::user()->category`. I've read I should use CONCAT, but after several tries, I only got a lot of errors. What's the best way to do this? :)

Comment: `->where('questions.category', 'LIKE', '%'.Auth::user()->category.'%');`

Comment: But isn't that the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

could be you can use  this sintax

```
  ->where('questions.category', 'like', '%' . Auth::user()->category . '%');
```

Comment: Thanks, but isn't that the other way around?

For example:
questions.category is car,
Auth::user()->category is car,bike,motor

Comment: @DiamondFox   .  you are asking for like sintax .. and my answer if for this .. what's the real problem ... you have  a  string to compare  ... or you have others problem ...

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion :). The syntax is correct, but in my case it has to be something like `->where('%questions.category%', 'like', Auth::user()->category);`, because questions.category is a subset of Auth::user()->category.

Comment: @DiamondFox   ..could be somethings like this   `->where(Auth::user()->category , 'like', concat('%' , questions.category, '%'));`

Comment: I think that's the right direction, but concat doesn't exist in Eloquent unfortunately :(. I tried these two versions:

`->where(DB::raw(Auth::user()->category, 'LIKE' , 'concat('%' , questions.category, '%')'));`
`->where(DB::raw('concat('%' , questions.category, '%')') , 'LIKE' , Auth::user()->category)`

..but both 'Division by Zero'

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions! :) I think I fixed it with this one:
`->where(DB::raw('concat(questions.category)') , 'LIKE' , '%'. Auth::user()->category .'%');`